# Display 3 different queries in one query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently I'm working on the database contains

customers

```
->
CUSTOMER_ID
NAME
ADDRESS
WEBSITE
CREDIT_LIMIT
```

orders

```
->
ORDER_ID
CUSTOMER_ID
STATUS
SALESMAN_ID
ORDER_DATE
```

order_items

```
->
ORDER_ID
ITEM_ID
PRODUCT_ID
QUANTITY
UNIT_PRICE
```

I want to create a SQL query to display

1. the number of customers with total order amount over the average amount of all orders,
2. the number of customers with total order amount under the average amount of all orders,
3. the number of customers with no orders and the total number of customers.
4. total number of customers

this is my attempt so far.(I know it's not enough)

> ```
> SELECT 'Number of customers with total purchase amount over average: ' || COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_id) AS "Report"
> FROM customers c
> INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
> INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
> WHERE 
> UNION
> SELECT 'Number of customers with total purchase amount below average: ' || COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_id) AS "Report"
> FROM customers c
> INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
> INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
> UNION
> SELECT 'Number of customers with no orders: ' || COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_id) AS "Report"
> FROM customers c
> LEFT JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
> WHERE      o.customer_id IS NULL
> UNION
> SELECT 'Total number of customers: ' || COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS "Report"
> FROM customers
> ORDER BY 1;
> ```

I just try to get the output for easier queries now so I've got the right output for 3, 4. But 1, 2... I've tried some queries but didn't work...

I appreciate it if you can help me with 1, 2.

I'd appreciate if anybody can answer my question.

Desired output

```
Report
------------------------------------------
Number of customers with total purchase amount over average: (number)
Number of customers with total purchase amount below average: (number)
Number of customers with no orders: (number)
Total number of customers: (number)
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) [mcve].

Comment: This reads like homework. Have you tried anything yet? Which issue are you facing?

Comment: wow thank you so much for the comments!!
And I'm sorry for my messy question. This is my first time posing question here.
So please bare with me.

Comment: It does read like homework.  The desired output format is bizarre for any real-world application -- the SQL should return the numerical data to be formatted this way using a reporting tool.  It looks like there has been strangeness added to get someone to demonstrate a specific skill.

Comment: ...and the question is vague.  `the number of customers with total order amount over the average amount of all orders`  Does that mean customers with totals over many orders that exceed the average order?  So if I order $12 three times, but the average single order is $30, I show up on the report?  Or does it mean customers whose largest or average or smallest order exceeded the average order?

Comment: @dougp
It is from an exercise quiz. I think it's made to see if quiz-taker can perform union properly. yea the question is very vague. I'm kinda confused too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windows function as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) FROM
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
       SUM(ORDER_TOTAL) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) AS CUST_TOTAL,
       AVG(ORDER_TOTAL) OVER () AS AVG_ALL
FROM
(SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       O.ORDER_ID,
       SUM(OI.UNIT_PRICE*OI.QUANTITY) AS ORDER_TOTAL
  FROM CUSTOMERS C
  JOIN ORDERS O ON O.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID
  JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI ON OI.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID,
         O.ORDER_ID))
WHERE CUST_TOTAL > AVG_ALL -- point 1
--WHERE CUST_TOTAL < AVG_ALL -- point 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Though I couldn't get the output I want, I've learned a lot from your solution!